# Conditional Tokens on Solana

Tags: token-extensions

I'm trying to experiment with conditional tokens on Solana. A link to the docs below from Gnosis is a reference to what they are. Their main use case is prediction markets esp. those with an AMM market design or a hybrid. [Polymarket](https://polymarket.com/) is probably the best example here. I was wondering if token extensions can be used to create conditional tokens. From what I've briefly looked into, it seems like transfer hooks may be an option here. If not, what extension would suit creating conditional tokens for a prediction market's use case?

https://docs.gnosis.io/conditionaltokens/

I appreciate any guidance, cheers!